# Simple htaccess rewrite/redirect to search page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a search form that sends a GET request to a page called search.php. I have rewrite rules set up in my htaccess file that rewrite certain things, like /search, to their respective pages. I simply want to take the search.php?q=query and rewrite it to /search/query.

Here is what I have.

```
RewriteRule search.php?q=(.*) /search/$1
RewriteRule search/(.*) search.php?q=$1 [nc]
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Here is the complete file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?p=404

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^images/.*\.jpg$ /images/default.jpg [L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?wghandcrafted.com/.*$ [NC]  
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|psd|js|swf|flv|png)$ /feed/ [R=302]  

RewriteRule ^(products|blog|feed|search|checkout|checkout)$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule products/cat/(.*)$ products.php?type=cat&cat=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule products/(.*)$ products.php?type=single&product=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog.php&post=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule feed/(.*) feed.phptype=$1 [nc]

RewriteRule search\.php?q=(.*)$ /search/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the first line perform a Redirect and the second perform a Rewrite

```
RewriteRule search\.php?q=(.*)$ /search/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [NC]
```

and move

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^images/.*\.jpg$ /images/default.jpg [L]
```

to the end of the set of rules.

Otherwise, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` rule is enacted before anything else, meaning that only requests for non-existant files will be handled by any rules below that line. As there is a `search.php` file, this prevents that rule from ever being reached.

Comment: Still not working... any other suggestions? I'll post my full .htaccess file.

Comment: @sun-tzu: See amended answer. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line is your problem, or, more specifically, it's placement.

Comment: I'm sorry to say .. but RewriteRule DOES NOT work with query string that way -- this will NOT work `search\.php?q=(.*)$`. RewriteRule pattern will match path part of the URL ONLY. Even if it would ... you extremely likely to get a rewrite loop (that's how mod_rewrite & .htaccess work)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this then? I just need my search query to go after the /search/<here>.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and here is a solution i found that worked for me, on my site the queries are being sent to index.php, I discovered if I had "^index.php$ /search/%1? [R=301]" as the first rewrite rule it will just error out because of the second rewrite rule making it just go in a loop so i replaced "^index.php$" with "^$" allowing it to still request the same file. It might not be the best solution, but a work around that works. Here is my working code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [R=301]

RewriteBase /search
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [NC]
```